# исключает ли использование synchronized, volatile?

Tags: java, многопоточность

исключает ли использование `synchronized`, `volatile`?

Происходит ли сброс данных из кэшей по завершению `synchronized` блока, и используют ли другие потоки потом обновлённые данные непосредственно из оперативки (игнорируя свои кэши)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, обращение к неволатильным переменным из синхронизированного блока гарантирует видимость, упорядоченность и атамарность. Но стоит иметь ввиду, что вход в синхронизированный блок на много медленнее обращения к волатильной переменной.

Answer (score 1):

[`volatile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4) действительно позиционируется как легковесная альтернатива [`synchronized`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1) когда речь идет о доступе к одной переменной.

На более ранних реализациях JVM мне доводилось также наблюдать феномен, когда несинхронизированный код работал как синхронизированный, когда в нем был включен трейсинг в консоль; когда же трейсинг выключался, код переставал работать. имхо, это было связано с тем, что `PrintStream.println` синхронизирован.

Однако я не видел такой спеки, которая бы определяла, что потоки должны синхронизировать кэши с общей памятью. Более того, спецификация [Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) говорит следующее:

> An implementation is free to produce any code it likes, as long as all resulting executions of a program produce a result that can be predicted by the memory model.

т.е. если некая реализация JVM будет работать эффективнее не сбрасывая весь кэш, а лишь те переменные, которые требуются согласно спецификации, то код, опирающийся на недокументированное поведение - сброс кэша потока, вероятно перестанет работать корректно.

Т.о. даже если сброс кэша и происходит в некоторых реализациях JVM, он не гарантирован спецификацией и не стоит опираться на это поведение в своей программе.